# How to merge two objects in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to retrieve from the database two contents: the first one with the field source equal to `"imported"` (which means that we import it from the excel spreadsheet), and the second one with `source != imported` (we create it from scratch). Attached is my code:

```
def index
    add_breadcrumb 'Projects', projects_path
    add_breadcrumb @project.name, @project
    add_breadcrumb "List #{@category.display_name} Content",    project_category_contents_path(@project, @category)
    @contents_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).imported.order('contents.created_at asc')
    @contents_not_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).not_imported.order('contents.created_at desc')
    @page = params[:page]
    @contents = @contents_not_imported << @contents_imported    
    @q = @contents.search(params[:q])
    @content = @q.result(distinct: true).page(@page).per(20)
end

@contents_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).imported.order('contents.created_at asc')

@contents_not_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).not_imported.order('contents.created_at desc')
```

And I want to combine the two results before showing it:

```
@contents = @contents_not_imported << @contents_imported
```

but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify how `.imported` and `.not_imported` are defined?

Comment: Can you let me know, whether my solution (using `merge`) worked or not? Otherwise I'll update my solution with some other ways.

Comment: PinnyM : here is the definition of imported and not_imported :  scope :imported, -> { where(source: "imported") }
  scope :not_imported, -> { where.not(source: "imported") }

Comment: Sharvy Ahmed : merge is showing the intersection between the imported content and the not imported so any element is showing up.

Comment: @ely_you - then there's no need for merging :) You can simply grab all whether they are imported or not - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If both of them are arrays and are having same type of objects you can do `Result = Arr1 | Arr1`

That also removes the duplicates. Its like boolean UNION. In your case `@contents = @contents_not_imported | @contents_imported`

Comment: undefined method `search' for #<Array:0xb6070a8>

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got this error : undefined method `search' for #<Array:0xb6070a8>

Comment: you can try + as well. thats just concatanation.

Comment: just curious can you paste the two arrays ? wanted to know how | failed.

Comment: If your question says "Unable to merge" people will give solution for that. If your existing code has issues please change the question :) its misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you want to concatenate results, but you also want to continue treating the combined results as an ActiveRelation (call `.search` on it).  Here's a simpler approach that avoids the need for concatenation in the first place.  You will need a more complex ORDER BY clause to accomplish this, however:

```
@page = params[:page]
@contents = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).
  order('CASE WHEN source <> "imported" THEN contents.created_at END desc, CASE WHEN source = "imported" THEN contents.created_at END asc')
@q = @contents.search(params[:q])
```

Comment: I was exploring your solution to learn something new, but I didn't get your solution. Where is the merging scoped collection, which was the requirement in the first place! :( How come this is a solution? Please don't get me wrong, I'm learning.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed - My point was that there isn't any reason to merge the contents in the first place.  You can easily get the desired contents by avoiding the filtering, since the 2 filters are inverses of each other and merging them together would cancel out the purpose of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating the arrays is done with the plus sign

You are getting `undefined method search for Array` because, concatenating will return you an array. And you can't call search method on that `Array`

**EDIT**

```
def index
    add_breadcrumb 'Projects', projects_path
    add_breadcrumb @project.name, @project
    add_breadcrumb "List #{@category.display_name} Content",      project_category_contents_path(@project, @category)
    contents_imported_ids = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).imported.order('contents.created_at asc').map(&:id)
    contents_not_imported_ids = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).not_imported.order('contents.created_at desc').map(&:id)
    @page = params[:page]
    contents_ids = contents_imported_ids + contents_not_imported_ids 
    contents = Content.where(content_ids)
    @contents = content_ids.collect{|id| contents.detect{|c| c.id == id}}
    @q = @contents.search(params[:q])
    @content = @q.result(distinct: true).page(@page).per(20)
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error if i use the plus sign. undefined method `search' for #<Array:0x73b7488>

Comment: it's becuase, this will return you an array. And you can't call `search` method on that. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Sontya for your answer, i tried it it works fine but i'm not getting the needed result ( the elements in the excel spreadsheet should keep the same order when importing them, and your solution does not give me that :) ).

Comment: Sontya : i'm getting error on "FIELD(id, #{contents_ids.join(',')})", UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function field. is this function predefines on rails?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Relation with the conditions of imported or not imported, after that, order all the records (if order is important to `@contents` and `@content`):

```
def index
  add_breadcrumb 'Projects', projects_path
  add_breadcrumb @project.name, @project
  add_breadcrumb "List #{@category.display_name} Content", project_category_contents_path(@project, @category)
  @contents_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).imported.order('contents.created_at asc')
  @contents_not_imported = Content.of_project(@project).with_category(@category).not_imported.order('contents.created_at desc')
  @page = params[:page]

  imported = @contents_imported.where_values.reduce(:and)
  not_imported = @contents_not_imported.where_values.reduce(:and)

  @contents = Content.where(imported.or(not_ipmorted)).order('CASE contents.imported WHEN true THEN contents.created_at asc ELSE contents.created_at desc END')

  @q = @contents.search(params[:q])
  @content = @q.result(distinct: true).page(@page).per(20)
end
```

Now you can call `Ransack#search` on `@contents` because it is an ActiveRecord::Relation. I assume that the imported scope take a field `contents.imported` with value true.

If I wrote this without errors, this must works.